# Haskell Parser fmap clarification

Tags: haskell

I have trouble in understanding the following fmap instance.Can someone explain me what fmap do(in this case) and how it can be used? Or write it less obfuscated?
Thanks!

```
newtype Parser a = P { getParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

instance Functor Parser where
    fmap f (P p) = P $ \s -> fmap (applyToFirst f) $ p s

{-|
    Applies a function to the first component of a pair.
-}
applyToFirst :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
applyToFirst f (x, y) = (f x, y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What does it do?**

It transforms a parser X into parser Y, where Y does the following: runs parser X and applies function f to first element of parsing result pair.

**How to use it?**

```
p1 :: Parser String
p1 = P (\s -> Just ("foo", "bar"))

p2 :: Parser String
p2 = fmap (\s -> s ++ s) p1
```

Now `(getParser p2) "whatever"` equals `Just ("foofoo", "bar")`.

**Could it be less obfuscated?**

It is not obfuscated actually. Haskell takes time to get used to.

Comment: What you mean "Y does the following" How can a data type do anything? Parser is a type.

Comment: Yeah, I mean `getParser` of course. The OP asks for intuition, so I might not be that precise. You are right though.

Comment: @CosminMihai In haskell, types represent not only "regular" values, but also computations. Stating that `Parser` is an instance of `Functor` formalizes that in your example.

Comment: @CosminMihai `P ...` is a value of type `Parser ...`, and a value can do something.